# Windows 8 Metro/Start resolution vs Desktop resolution

Tags: resolution, windows-8-preview, modern-ui

I am testing Windows 8 on my HTPC connected to a HDTV in my bedroom.  The TV is 720p, but can scale down 1080i resolutions.  I was running at 720p and the Metro/Start page wasnt working correctly.  After [some research](http://it-diary.com/windows/windows-8-new-features-screenshots/) I found you need a minimum of 768 pixels in height for the Metro/Start page to function.

I switched my TV to 1080i (scales it to 720p) and the  Metro/Start screen and apps work and look fine.  However, my desktop becomes way to small to see at that resolution.  The desktop looks best at 720p.

Is it possible to have the Metro/Start page and apps at 1080i, while my desktop is at 720p?

Comment: remember this is pre beta software and may not be fully functional and for sure full of bugs

Answer (score 5):

Unless you have assembly skills, you can't get the resolution to switch in between.

The Windows 8 *Developer* Preview isn't meant to be used as a HTPC OS in a bedroom; similarly, a TV isn't meant to be used to watch your desktop; make yourself something like [Boxee](http://www.boxee.tv/make) which is much easier...

Comment: Well I disagree with that.  I use the TVs for viewing desktop and apps all the time.  I rarely sit on my desktop PCs at home anymore, unless I need to some long term work which requires a lot of typing.

Comment: @Keltari: If I want to take high quality pictures I would take a photo camera and not a mobile phone, I won't be trying to get the mobile phone to act the same like the photo camera. Who in their right mind would try that if he could take the photo camera to do that? And on top of that, you're talking about the Windows 8 DP which makes this even more localized...

Comment: Im not asking you to like my methods, just asking a question if it was possible

Comment: Which I answered in the first sentence, not counting in sloppy workarounds...

Comment: Tom let's try to stay on the subject of the question here: "is it possible?" You are right though that it likely is not possible to switch resolutions on the fly like that.

Comment: @nhinkle: There is nothing wrong with my second paragraph and comment, they are both remarks intended to learn the reader that if you go for alternative non-common solutions you'll end up with near impossible problems. I'm not planning to start a heated discussion on that, I'm just saying that he might want to reconsider his whole situation rather than to focus on such small problem. Of course such small problem can be solved through a non-stable work-around through AutoHotkey, or with some passion one could adjust the OS to switch the resolution between both modes. *Fishing whales is hard...*